# Add placeholder to a network image in flutter

Tags: flutter, api, dart, networking

#### I have many network images that are being displayed in my app.

*When these images are being loaded... Nothing shows on the screen (the screen remains blank for about 3-5 seconds, time for the image to be displayed)*

#### How to show something like a loader or animation while the image is being loaded?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Image.network build in property

```
    Image.network(
      "https://www.kindpng.com/imgv/ioJmwwJ_dummy-profile-image-jpg-hd-png-download/",
      loadingBuilder: (BuildContext context, Widget child, ImageChunkEvent loadingProgress) {
        if (loadingProgress == null) return child;
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(
              value: loadingProgress.expectedTotalBytes != null
                ? loadingProgress.cumulativeBytesLoaded / loadingProgress.expectedTotalBytes
                : null,
           ),
         );
       },
     ),
```

Comment: Voilà.... This one is definitely the Best I think 

Answer (score 2):

Try using FadeInImage(), it has properties of placeHolder and errorPlaceHolder

Answer (score 1):

You can use [cached_network_image](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image) package.

```
CachedNetworkImage(
        placeholder: (context, url) => Container(color : Colors.red), // Add whatever you want to display.
        imageUrl: url,
      )
```

Comment: Thanks for this Yashraj ! But I would like to achieve it without the use of any package...  I'll definitely use a FadeInImage widget

Answer (score 1):

```
class CachedImage extends StatelessWidget {
final String image;
final double radius;
final double imageWidth;
final double imageHeight;
final double imageArea;
final BoxFit fit;
final Color color;
final String placeHolder;
final double width;
CachedImage({
this.color = colorPrimary,
this.image = '',
this.radius = 30,
this.imageHeight = 70,
this.imageWidth = 70,
this.imageArea = 30,
this.fit = BoxFit.cover,
this.placeHolder = IMG_PLACEHOLDER,
this.width = 1.0,
});

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Container(
  width: imageWidth,
  height: imageHeight,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    border: Border.all(
      color: color,
      width: width,
    ),
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(radius),
  ),
  child: ClipRRect(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(radius),
    child: CachedNetworkImage(
        placeholder: (context, url) => Container(
              child: Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                  valueColor: new AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color> 
         (colorWhite),
                ),
              ),
              height: imageArea,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0))),
            ),
        errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Material(
              child: Image.asset(
                placeHolder,
                width: imageWidth,
                height: imageHeight,
                fit: BoxFit.fill,
              ),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0)),
              clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
            ),
        imageUrl: image,
        width: imageWidth,
        height: imageHeight,
        fit: fit),
   ),
  );
 }
}
```

You can use this custom widget created using **CachedNetworkImage** package. In which in case the image is not loaded from network we are using **CircularProgressBarIndicator** while in case of error that the network image is not loaded we can use error widget and can pass an alternative image from assets.

Comment: Thanks Kamran! But I'll prefer doing it without any package. I'll definitely use the FadeInImage widget and its placeholder attribute 

Answer (score 1):

use this package https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image

```
Widget getNetworkImage({
  double? height = 45.0,
  double? width = 45.0,
  double? borderRadius = 10.0,
  bool? showCircularProgressIndicator, //<== this is for loader
  required String url,
}) {
  return ClipRRect(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(borderRadius ?? 0.0),
    child: SizedBox(
      height: height,
      width: width,
      child: CachedNetworkImage(
        fit: BoxFit.fill,
        imageUrl: url,
        placeholder: (context, url) {
          showCircularProgressIndicator ??= true;
          if (showCircularProgressIndicator == true) {
            return Center(
                child: Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(7),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(color: const Color(0xff0C59EA).withOpacity(0.35), borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
            ));
          } else {
            return const Center(child: SizedBox());
          }
        },
        errorWidget: (context, url, error) { //<== if you get error in image
          return Image.asset(((height ?? 45) >= 100 || (width ?? 45.0) >= 100) ? Assets.imagesCommonPlaceholder : Assets.imagesLogoPlaceholder, fit: BoxFit.cover);//<== use your app placeholder or logo for better UX.
        },
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

try using this way.

```
 getNetworkImage(
      url: "your-image-url-here",
      borderRadius: 15, //<== if you like to give border radius
      height: 60, //<== if you like to give height
     width: 60, //<== if you like to give width
   )
```

Comment: Thanks for this Ravis. I tried it out and it works perfectly. But I'll definitely use FadeInImage widget as it is a built-in widget.